# AWS Cognito and adminCreateUser without password

Tags: amazon-cognito

Is it possible to create a user by Admin without a password and instead get a temporary password on the email, get time-limited URL for the link to the form where the user should set password directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No this is not possible. You can set a temporary password and then force user to change it as soon as they log in.